# Embedding google street view on website

Tags: javascript, google-maps

On a website I am building I have a google map as a background of a contact form. It looks nice, but I would like to convert the google map into the google street view to get a nice picture of the building so they know exactly where they are going.

I have been trying to follow [the google site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed) to convert my code over to the street view version, but I seem to be missing something and can't quite figure out what.

Some help would be gratefully appreciated. I've never done a street view map before.

The code I have currently looks like this

```
 var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 20,
            center: map_center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), mapOptions ); 

        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos_a1, pos_b1), //my position I have stored as variables to make it cleaner
            map: map,
        });
```

and I have tried

```
var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 1,
            center: map_center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false
        }

        var map = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ), mapOptions ); 
        myPano.setVisible(true);

        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos_a1, pos_b1),
            map: map,
        });
```

but the map just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

A StreetViewPanorama expects a `position`-parameter instead of `center`.

Furthermore you use 2 different variables(`map` and myPano)

This would work(when there is a panorama available for the given position):

```
    var panoOptions = {
        position: map_center,
        scrollwheel: false
    }

    var myPano = new google.maps
                    .StreetViewPanorama( document.getElementById( 'map-canvas' ),
                                         panoOptions );
```